# Tomcat not picking the showing 404 on index.html

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

i am new to the servelests and building a web application.
When i create the new html file in myproejct under the web pages folder in netbeans and compilling that file it shows 404 error  with following URL

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/
```

but when i change this url to

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/index.html
```

it shows the page..

and also when creating **index.jsp** instead of **index.html** and compile in netbeans it is shown in the browser

why this happen ?????
any hint ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976160/how-does-tomcat-find-the-home-page-of-my-web-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your index.html under `WEB-INF` or `WebContent`?

It should be under `WebContent` folder and also map properly in your web.xml.

Comment: my document lies in the web folder.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976160/how-does-tomcat-find-the-home-page-of-my-web-app