# IntelliJ IDEA stopped deploying webapp on tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

[image: This is the project I have]
It uses tomcat to deploy. It used to run perfectly fine and when I pressed "Run" it opened a index.jsp in my web-browser which I used as starting navigation point.

But after I decided to try and run it without IDE, by copying contents into tomcat/webapps, something changed, although I'm not sure if it's connected. Now when I press "Run" inside project it just opens up a [image: default Tomcat homepage] although absolutely nothing from my project got changed. And if you go into manager from there there are no applications running aside from manager itself, not even ones in /webapps in tomcat directory.

What exactly happened and how can I change it back?

[image: Here are Configuration Settings]

UPDATE it's started working somehow. No idea why and what happened

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has a `web.xml` file where you can define your `<welcome-file-list>`

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976385/2601113)

Also you can compile your webApp as a .war to deploy it on your Tomcat server.

Follow the instructions in this [link](http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-deploy-a-java-web-application-on-tomcat) if you need help.

Comment: Adding <welcome-file-list> to project's web.xml didn't help. It's not exactly the problem. IntelliJ used to just deploy only one applitcation which is the project that is currently open in it. Now it's doesn't even do that. I know I can do it manually but it's much easier to do changes within IDE and just press restart to see results than recompiling.