# WAR deployment in tomcar

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I need some advise over here. I have deployed a java based app on tomcat server. Tomcat server is installed on aws cloud. I am using the URL as hostname:portno/WAR file name to run the app and When i try to hit the app on browser it throws an error 404. However, when i add index.html after the URL or any other name with .html extsn like for ex hostname:port/warname/abc.html my app runs fine. Can you please advise why it is not running without index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question has got to do something with the accepted answer in this thread

[How does Tomcat find the HOME PAGE of my Web App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976160/how-does-tomcat-find-the-home-page-of-my-web-app)

Simply put, Under WEB-INF/web.xml a home page has to be defined, if nothing is defined then what ever is defined in TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml file will be considered as home page by tomcat server

so in your case I think you did not define a specific home page in WEB-INF/web.xml, that is why tomcat was searching for index.html page which is as per default configuration but index.html is not available to tomcat, so you were seeing 404 error. As soon as you put index.html file there then everything started to work for you